# Why is a Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group not closed under complex scalar multiplication?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let the set $\mathcal{g}$ be the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group $G$. Then my book asserts that $\mathcal{g}$ is a real vector space because it's closed under real scalar multiplication. My question why is it not closed under complex scalar multiplication?

If $X \in \mathcal{g}$ and the corresponding exponentiated matrix $e^{tX}\in G$ ($t \in  \mathbb{R}$), I don't see why a multiplication with a complex scalar $C$ of $X$, namely $CX$, will make $CX\notin \mathcal{g}$.

Comment: Could you provide a name of the book/picture of the passage?

Comment: "An Introduction to Tensors and Group Theory for Physicists" by N. Jeevanjee page 116.

Comment: It says on page 116 "$gl(n,\Bbb{C})$ can also be considered a complex vector space but we will not consider it as such in this text"

Comment: So? I don't see your point.

Comment: I'm saying $g$ is real if $G$ is real and $g$ is complex if $G$ is complex, but they aren't considering the last situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is a real Lie group, so in particular it is a real manifold, then its tangent spaces will be real vector spaces. In particular its Lie algebra will be a real vector space. If, on the other hand, $G$ is a complex Lie group, then its Lie algebra will be a complex vector space.

Comment: Hey thanks, but is that a definition or something that can be proven?

Comment: @nougako It is really part of the definition of a manifold. Go back and recall how one defines a tangent space of a real manifold. You'll see that it doesn't make sense to try to give it a complex structure.

Comment: Actually in the book I am talking about it's written as a proposition: 

"Let $g$ be the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group $G$. Then $g$ is a real vector space, is closed under commutators, and all elements of g obey the Jacobi identity."

As you see, this proposition doesn't specify anything about whether the Lie groups is real or not.

Comment: Could the author be sloppy in not restricting $G$ to be real Lie group when he states that proposition?
Also, suppose I consider $SU(2)$, then the corresponding Lie algebra must be a complex vector space?

Comment: @nougako Yes, it is likely that the author is only considering real Lie groups for now. $SU(n)$, despite being defined as a submanifold of a complex vector space, is actually only a real manifold.

Comment: That's due to the Lie algebra for $SU(n)$ turns out to be anti-Hermitian and anti-Hermitian matrix is in real vector space?

Comment: @nougako Almost. That's the Lie algebra for $U(n)$. The Lie algebra for $SU(n)$ is the subspace of traceless matrices. But yes, it is merely a real vector space, hence $SU(n)$ is only a real Lie group.